How to resolve python modules in another folder in workspace
I am trying to figure out if its possible to configure VS Code in such a way that I have  multiple repos loaded in a workspace and I want to have the editor with a file loaded from one folder able to resolve and provide assistance for python files in another folder.
in a single workspace I have:
repo1
\src
    \including_script.py
repo2
\src
    \mypackage
              \mysubpackage
                           \myincluded.py
    

I would like including script to reference the contents of myincluded.py via the package hierarchy like this:
from mypackage.mysubpackage.myincluded import function_I_use

I have defined a venv for repo1 and I have a .env file in repo1 with a python path that has the absolute path of the src directory in repo2.   This has not helped.   Thoughs, suggestions?

Does repo2 include a setup.py file or pyproject.toml and does it have __init__.py files in the package directories, or is it configured as a NameSpace package.

No setup.py or toml file.   I do have empty init.py at the mypackage and mysubpackage levels.

The package indicator file is __init__.py not init.py...

@SergeBallesta I typed in the underscores and they were taken as formatting characters. whoops.

@starball not specifically the question/answer I was looking for and I had actually read through that whole question and answers.   Turns out one of the suggestions there is what I did that worked for me.   I will document as an answer to my question later tonight.  Not sure its the best way bit it does work.

Sorry I didn't get to follow up on your response to my question earlier, but hopefully from the other post you found that updating PYTHONPATH is likely the simplest solution for your scenario.

@nigh_anxiety the right path for what I wanted was python > analysis : extraPaths

@LhasaDad.  In my experience, that will make Pylance happy and remove the warning, but on its own it doesn't actually allow the import to work when the code is run without also updating PythonPath or doing an editable install with pip.

@nigh_anxiety No argument there.  but all I needed was resolution and code completion.   The two repos are managing different assets that will interact but it would be impossible to include all I need as some of the imported modules are part of a vendor's product and not available other than at run time.
